# Not able to connect to SQL, ERROR = ServerVersion 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting an error that I can't find an answer for anywhere online. It says

> ServerVersion 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

I've blocked out some words as not to compromise our data. It's not even making the connection.

[image: Screenshot]

This connection string works in previous application version (Visual Studio 2012, .NET Framework 4.5.2 using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql) so I know it's not the credentials.  We are re-writing the old application so the new one is using Visual Studio 2015, .NET Framework 4.5.2, and System.Data.SqlClient.

Here is the `web.config` connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DataConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=mydatabaseserver\tst1;Initial Catalog=LeaseData;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=myID;Password=mypassword" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

This is my c# code calling to the database using my connection string that is available in the `web.config`.

```
public static DataTable ContractDetails(string contractID, string pointOfContact)
    {
        string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DataConnection"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        {
            try
            {
                if (connString.Length > 0)
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spNameOfStoredProcedure"))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Connection = conn;
                            da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractID", contractID);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PointOfContact", pointOfContact);
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                            {
                                da.Fill(dt);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (SystemException)
            {

            }
        }
```

Let me know if there is anything else that would be helpful in solving this issue!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that  ContractID parameter  is expected to be an nvarchar in your stored procedure?

Comment: I dont see a conn.Open() anywhere, you need to open your connection to the DB before you can execute commands.

Comment: @Bearcat9425 Not for an Adapter, you don't.

Comment: Your posted code and your image aren't quite in sync, so I'm not sure what we are looking at.  Why do you have empty Try-Catches?

Comment: Yes, ContractID parameter is an nvarchar.

Comment: The Catch is empty because we use a proprietary logging system that I omitted for the sake of privacy.

Answer (score 3):

In your screenshot you are viewing the properties of the connection prior to the connection being opened by the DataAdapter. Thus the connection is closed at that point - hence the InvalidOperationException on the call to ServerVersion. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.serverversion(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I'm getting the same error you see in the screenshot as I am running the code that I've included.  I took the screenshot before correcting and changing the logic.

Comment: The code you have shared does not call a get on the ServerVersion property which suggests that the call is made from the proprietary logging system you mention. This may be hiding the root error. What line actually throws the error when you step through? And is the ServerVersion error definitely the one that is intially thrown at this point?

Comment: I ended up fixing this by removing the try-catch and starting with the very basics, it then gave me a more detailed error that the stored procedure couldn't be found in the specified database.  STUPID MISTAKE- I found that the stored proc that I was using was in a different connection string.  It just would have been nice to have better error messages!

Comment: So the error you were getting was being raised by the proprietary logging system in the catch and thus masking the original error? So I was right? ;-)

Comment: Actually you weren't right.  The proprietary logging system was stripped out of it too.  :)

Comment: @GeekWurk, actually he is right, if you tried to get the ServerVersion number  `Debug.WriteLine(CON.ServerVersion)`, it will be returned with no exceptions, you can not simply evaluate ServerVersion while Connection not yet OPEN.